# Set seekbar indeterminate on true at button click

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a SeekBar:

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
```

I have for it a custom indeterminate drawable set in xml:

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
```

From code

```
seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

works, but when I want to set indeterminate to true at on button click doesn't work - the seekbar become black.

```
 Button startIndeterminateMode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startIndeterminateMode);
        startIndeterminateMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                seeekBar.setIndeterminate(true);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if seekbar supports indeterminate mode, You should rather have seekbar and Progressbar in a single layout and make them `visible` and `GONE` alternatively depending upon onClick

Comment: supports indeterminate - because I actually made it indeterminate...but I need a way to make in to the defaut state...